# Insert data into database from by selecting dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to insert data into database from a student registration form. Data going into student table and some part of that form data going into Applied table. Typed in data going in STUDENT table and selected course from dropdown list going in APPLIED table. I am not able to pickup the CourseID from selected course.

Problem is in this code in controller:

```
var apply = new Applied { StudentID = application.StudentID, CourseID = application.CourseID  };
```

In debug mode it's not showing any data in CourseID.

Following is my code.

VIEWMODEL:

```
public class Application2
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }        //PK

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public double PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public DateTime AppliedDate { get; set; }

    public int AppliedID { get; set; }      //PK

    public int CourseID { get; set; }       //FK

}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult DepartmentList()
{
    var departments = db.Departments.OrderBy(x => x.DpName).ToList();

    if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return Json(new SelectList(
                    departments,
                    "DepartmentID",
                    "DpName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                    );
    }

    return View(departments);
}

public ActionResult CourseList(int DepartmentID)
{
    var courses = db.Courses.Where(x => x.DepartmentID == DepartmentID).ToList();

    if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return Json(new SelectList(courses, "CourseID", "CourseName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    return View(courses);
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Application2 application)
{
    var student = new Student { StudentID = application.StudentID, FirstName = application.FirstName, LastName = application.LastName, DateOfBirth = application.DateOfBirth, Address = application.Address, PhoneNumber = application.PhoneNumber, Email = application.Email, AppliedDate = application.AppliedDate };

    var apply = new Applied { StudentID = application.StudentID, CourseID = application.CourseID  }; 

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var db = new RegistrarsContext())


            db.Students.Add(student);

            db.Applied.Add(apply).ApplicationStatus = Status.Applied;

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Student");
    }

    return  View();
}
```

Following is the VIEW :

```
@model StudentsRegistration.ViewModels.Application2

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Student Appication";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout2.cshtml";
}
<h2>Student Application Form</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Application2", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Student Details </h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentID)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppliedDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AppliedDate)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AppliedDate)
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="Departments">Departments</label>
            <select id="Departments" name="Departments"></select>
            <br /><br />

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="Courses">Courses</label>
            <select id="Courses" name="Courses"></select>

        </div>

        @section scripts {
            <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.getJSON("/Application2/Departments/List", function (data) {
                var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";
                $.each(data, function (i, country) {
                    items += "<option value='" + country.Value + "'>" + country.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $("#Departments").html(items);
            });

            $("#Departments").change(function () {
                $.getJSON("@Url.Action("CourseList", "Application2")?DepartmentID=" + $("#Departments").val(), function (data) {
                    var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";
                    $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                        items += "<option value='" + state.Value + "'>" + state.Text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $("#Courses").html(items);
                });
            });
        });
            </script>
        }
            <br /><br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your View code also

Comment: this piece of code is not in the view. should i include this. can you please explain it bit more.

Comment: no, its still not passing any value to:           var apply = new Applied { StudentID = application.StudentID, CourseID = application.CourseID  };

Comment: Your `<select>` has `name="Courses"` (it would need to be `name="CourseID"` in order to bind to property `CourseID`). (And go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics. Get rid of all that first javasript/ajax and pass the `SelectList` to the view using a view model and strongly bind to your model using `@Html.DropDownListFor()`). And to correctly implement cascading dropdownlists, refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the create tables script:

```
USE [Breaz]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Applied]    Script Date: 9/6/2016 2:13:55 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Applied](
    [AppliedId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CourseId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Applied] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AppliedId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[CourseDepartment]    Script Date: 9/6/2016 2:13:55 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CourseDepartment](
    [CourseDepartmentId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CourseId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CourseDepartment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CourseDepartmentId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Courses]    Script Date: 9/6/2016 2:13:55 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Courses](
    [CourseId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CourseName] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Courses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CourseId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Department]    Script Date: 9/6/2016 2:13:55 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Department](
    [DepartmentId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentName] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Department] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DepartmentId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Student]    Script Date: 9/6/2016 2:13:55 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student](
    [StudentId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [datetime] NULL,
    [Address] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [AppliedDate] [varchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Student] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StudentId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Applied]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Applied_Courses] FOREIGN KEY([CourseId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Courses] ([CourseId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Applied] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Applied_Courses]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Applied]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Applied_Student] FOREIGN KEY([StudentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Student] ([StudentId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Applied] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Applied_Student]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CourseDepartment]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CourseDepartment_Courses] FOREIGN KEY([CourseId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Courses] ([CourseId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CourseDepartment] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CourseDepartment_Courses]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CourseDepartment]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CourseDepartment_Department] FOREIGN KEY([DepartmentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Department] ([DepartmentId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CourseDepartment] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CourseDepartment_Department]
GO
```

Use the EDMX generated model plus this view:

```
namespace Testy2.Models
{
    public class StudentView
    {
        public Student student { get; set; }
        public Applied applied { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
public class Application2Controller : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Application2/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult DepartmentList()
    {
        var departments = new List<Department>();
        using (var db = new Registrars())
        {
            departments = db.Departments.OrderBy(x => x.DepartmentName).ToList();
            if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return Json(new SelectList(
                            departments,
                            "DepartmentID",
                            "DepartmentName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                            );
            }
        }
        return View(departments);
    }

    public ActionResult CourseList(int DepartmentID)
    {
        using (var db = new Registrars())
        {
            var courses = db.CourseDepartments.Where(x => x.DepartmentId == DepartmentID).Select(
                p => new { CourseId = p.CourseId, CourseName = p.Cours.CourseName }).ToList();
            if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return Json(new SelectList(courses, "CourseID", "CourseName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return View(courses);
        }
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(StudentView application)
    {
        var student = new Student
        {
            StudentId = application.student.StudentId,
            FirstName = application.student.FirstName,
            LastName = application.student.LastName,
            DateOfBirth = application.student.DateOfBirth,
            Address = application.student.Address,
            PhoneNumber = application.student.PhoneNumber,
            Email = application.student.Email,
            AppliedDate = application.student.AppliedDate
        };

        var apply = new Applied
        {
            StudentId = application.student.StudentId,
            CourseId = application.applied.CourseId
        };

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var db = new Registrars())
            {
                db.Students.Add(student);
                db.Applieds.Add(apply);

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Application2");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }

}
```

Here is the view:

```
@model Testy2.Models.StudentView

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Student Appication";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Student Application Form</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Application2", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Student Details </h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.student.StudentId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.student.StudentId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.student.StudentId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.student.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.student.FirstName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.student.FirstName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.student.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.student.LastName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.student.LastName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.student.DateOfBirth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.student.DateOfBirth)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.student.DateOfBirth)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.student.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.student.Address)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.student.Address)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.student.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.student.PhoneNumber)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.student.PhoneNumber)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.student.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.student.Email)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.student.Email)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.student.AppliedDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.student.AppliedDate)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.student.AppliedDate)
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="Departments">Departments</label>
            <select id="Departments" name="Departments"></select>
            <br /><br />

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="applied_CourseId">Courses</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.applied.CourseId, new SelectList(new List<string>()), new { id = "applied_CourseId" })
        </div>

        @section scripts {
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $.getJSON("/Application2/DepartmentList", function (data) {
                        var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";
                        $.each(data, function (i, country) {
                            items += "<option value='" + country.Value + "'>" + country.Text + "</option>";
                        });
                        $("#Departments").html(items);
                    });

                    $("#Departments").change(function () {
                        $.getJSON("@Url.Action("CourseList", "Application2")?DepartmentID=" + $("#Departments").val(), function (data) {
                            var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";
                            $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                                items += "<option value='" + state.Value + "'>" + state.Text + "</option>";
                            });
                            $("#applied_CourseId").html(items);
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
        }
        <br /><br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```